# Understanding auction types

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, equivalence

I'm working on a project in the advertising space where advertisers bid on inventory. I'm trying to simply understand a practical example of the different auction algorithms. I have spent several days getting to the bottom of it, but unfortunately many examples are from dense scientific papers where the math is a bit over my head (including some of the wikipedia links).

I'm hoping someone here can illuminate and fill in the missing pieces from my example below.

**background:**

- Advertisers are bidding on an ad impression within an ad unit
- Sometimes, only a single item is being sold (1 ad impression per 1 ad unit = 1 winner per auction)
- Other times multiple items are being sold (3 ad spots per 1 ad unit = 3 ad impressions = 3 auctions = 3 winners). Think of Google search ads where there's 3 spots above the search results.

Now here are the main auction types that I'm trying to understand. I have placed wikipedia entries as links in all the headings:

### First-Priced Auction

Easily understood by the following example:

```
Bid #1   0.35
Bid #2   0.20
Bid #3   0.15
Bid #4   0.05
```

- **Single auction:** Bid #1 wins, clearing price @ `0.35`
- **Multiple item auction:** Bid #1 @ `0.35`, Bid #2 @ `0.20`

All my multiple item examples will assume 2 items are being sold, with 4 total bidders.

### [Vickrey Second-Price Auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickrey_auction)

It's my understanding that a "Vickrey auction" only takes place when a single item is for sale, so we only have one example here:

```
Bid #1   0.35
Bid #2   0.20
Bid #3   0.15
Bid #4   0.05
```

- **Single auction:** Bid #1 wins, clearing price @ `0.21`

I do still have a question with this however, as I get conflicting information of whether the clearing price is `0.21` (the lowest bid + 1 bid increment) or `0.20`, which is simply the 2nd highest bid.

### [Vickrey–Clarke–Groves Second-Price Auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickrey%E2%80%93Clarke%E2%80%93Groves_auction)

- Used by Facebook
- Used by Google for non-search ads
- This is explained [here](https://www.aeaweb.org/conference/2014/retrieve.php?pdfid=494) in a paper by Google, as well as [here](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emilgrom/publishedarticles/Lovely%20but%20Lonely%20Vickrey%20Auction-072404a.pdf)

```
Bid #1   0.35
Bid #2   0.20
Bid #3   0.15
Bid #4   0.05
```

- **Single auction:** ...
- **Multiple item auction:** ...

### [Generalized Second-Price Auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_second-price_auction)

- Was once used by Facebook, which switched to VCG
- Used by Google only for search ads
- Talked about [here](https://www.nber.org/papers/w11765.pdf) by Yahoo! I believe this is quite a popular paper, and have found this [summary](https://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs455/fall11/gsp_presentation.pdf) of it in slideshow form.

```
Bid #1   0.35
Bid #2   0.20
Bid #3   0.15
Bid #4   0.05
```

- **Single auction:** ...
- **Multiple item auction:** ...

### Question

Essentially I'm wanting to fill in my understanding on the subtle differences in all 3 second-price examples. You will see I have put `...` where I simply don't know, and would like help filling in the clearing price for both single and multiple item auctions.

Even the Vickrey auction (where I filled in the clearing price) might be wrong, as I see things like [this](https://keycult.com/blogs/typings/the-vickrey-auction-and-why-were-using-it) article which to me goes against everything how I think a Vickrey auction works. I can't tell if what I'm reading is wrong, as many articles give conflicting information. I feel the truth is not in these blog posts, but in the actual mathematical definitions which I don't understand.

Comment: I cannot discern a clear, specific question here.  Could you please include one in your post?

Comment: Sorry, the question is where I have written `...` I am looking for a practical example of how it would look. Ill include it in my post